# Whats the best way to switch between a normal view and a GLsurface view, Android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, rendering, surfaceview

I am currently making a game, the game has a start screen and the main game screen.

My question is what is the best way to switch between the two views.

The start screen consists of just a couple of buttons one being "start game", when this is clicked GLsurface view to be created.

If i create the GLsurface view at the begining and bind the renderer here then anything from the GL surface view is displayed on top of the start up screen.

I thought i could create a viewflipper which would default to the start screen and then just create the glsurface view within the onclick method for the start button, but this doesnt seem to like having the GLsurface view in it.

Does viewFlipper support Glsurface view or is there a better way round this.

Thanks.

Comment: Android Breakout (https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/) does this using two activities, though it sounds like you want something more animated.  Bear in mind that GLSurfaceView has two components, the transparent View part and a separately-composited Surface, so animating the GLSurfaceView's view may not yield the effect you want.

Comment: @fadden thanks for the suggestion, i am sure there are other ways to do this but your suggestion worked fine. Write a more detailed answer and i will accecpt it. 1 other thing to note when doing like this is that if you are constantly going back and fourth between the two activities it is possible to create more than 1 instance of each. i need to check that i am not doing this.

Comment: Done.  Also added a note about TextureView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use two activities, and just switch between them.

The trouble here is that `ViewFlipper` can only affect the "view" part of the `GLSurfaceView`, which is just a transparent hole.  The surface where the GL rendering happens is composited separately, behind the layer with the view content, so it [cannot be animated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085300/) this way.

An example of using two activities in a GL game can be found in [Android Breakout](https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/), which uses one activity for configuration and "start", and another for the game itself.

If you really want the `ViewFlipper` animation you could render into a [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html), but your app would have to handle a number of things that `GLSurfaceView` does for you.  `TextureView` is also less efficient than `SurfaceView`.